# Search Multiple Arrays for

Tags: php, arrays, search, multidimensional-array

I have officially hit a wall and I cannot figure out the solution to this issue. Any help would be much appreciated! I have tried [array_intersect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) but it just keeps running against the first array in the function, that wont work.

I have an infinite amounts of arrays (I'll show 4 for demonstration purposes), for example:

```php
// 1.
array(1,2,3,4,5);
// 2.
array(1,3,5);
// 3.
array(1,3,4,5);
// 4.
array(1,3,5,6,7,8,9);
```

I need to figure out how to search all the arrays and find only the numbers that exist in all 4 arrays. In this example I need to only pull out the values from the arrays - 1, 3 & 5.

PS: In all reality, it would be best if the function could search against a multi dimensional array and extract only the numbers that match in all the arrays within the array.

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Is this a homework assignment or a hypothetical scenario for an actual application?  Because the approach is going to differ depending on that.  For example, you say an infinite amount of arrays, but are the arrays really no more than about 8 items each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fun question!  This worked:

```
function arrayCommonFind($multiArray) {

    $result = $multiArray[0];
    $count = count($multiArray);
    for($i=1; $i<$count; $i++) {
        foreach($result as $key => $val) {
            if (!in_array($val, $multiArray[$i])) {
                unset($result[$key]);
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Note that you can just use $multiArray[0] (or *any* sub-array) as a baseline and check all the others against that since any values that will be in the final result must necessarily be in all individual subarrays.

Answer (score 0):

If it's in a multidimensional array you could

```
$multiDimensional = array(/* Your arrays*/);
$found = array_pop($multiDimensional);
foreach($multiDimensional as $subArray)
{
  foreach($found as $key=>$element)
  { 
    if(!in_array($element, $subArray)
    {
      unset($found[$key]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If its not in the first sub array we can ignore it immediately, then if if its not in the subsequent arrays we remove it from the found array and don't look for it in future.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but I ran this and I am not sure how to spit out the results:

Comment: `var_dump($found);` or `print_r($found)`;

Comment: $a = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$b = array(1,4,5);
$c = array(1,2,3,4);
$d = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);

$multiDimensional = array($a, $b, $c, $d);
$found = array_pop($multiDimensional);
foreach($multiDimensional as $subArray){
  foreach($found as $key => $element){ 
    if(!in_array($subArray, $element)){
      unset($found[$key]);
    }
  }
}

Comment: I ran "var_dump($found);" and I got this back: array(0) { }

Comment: Sorry i got mixed up, in_array() arguments shoudl be the other way around needle, haystack. Crazy php. I'll correct answer

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

Find the numbers that exist in both array 1 and 2. Then compare those results with array 3 to find the common numbers again. Keep going as long as you want.

Is this what you are getting at?

Comment: That wont work, because the values may swap back and forth interms of what items go in each array. Array 2 may contain array 1 values, and array 1 may contain array 3 values, etc. There is never a set pattern of what fills the array. That is why I only need to find the values that exist in each array that are common no matter what elements that are in the array.

Comment: hm, but if some element is not mutual for arrays 1 & 2, doesn't matter is it appear in arrays 2,3,...n. In your example 1,3 & 5 are mutual for arrays 1 & 2, so comparing result with array 3 and later with array 4 (and so on) will return same result - new array with 1,3 & 5 as elements.

Comment: in other words, if you want result-set of mutual elements of all arrays, that result-set can be only shorter or equal than result you got comparing first two arrays, not longer (new elements can't appear because they don't exist in first two arrays).

Answer (score 0):

Per your comment on my other question here is a better solution:

```
<?php
// 1. merge the arrays
$merged_arrays = array_merge( $arr1, $arr2, $arr3, $arr4, ...);
// 2. count the values
$merged_count = array_count_values( $merged_arrays );
// 3. sort the result for elements that only matched once
for( $merged_count as $key => $value ){
    if ($value == 1) {
        // 4. unset the values that didn't intersect
        unset($merged_count($key));
    }
}
// 5. print the resulting array
print_r( $merged_count );
```

Answer (score 0):

Performing iterated `in_array()` calls followed by `unset()` is excessive handling and it overlooks the magic of `array_intersect()` which really should be the hero of any solid solution for this case.

Here is a lean iterative function:

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f55a7e7a1f476cc70c034ac19243a55758b908f7))

```
function array_intersect_multi($arrays){ // iterative method
    while(sizeof($arrays)>1){
        $arrays[1]=array_intersect($arrays[0],$arrays[1]);  // find common values from first and second subarray, store as (overwrite) second subarray
        array_shift($arrays);  // discard first subarray (reindex $arrays)
    }
    return implode(', ',$arrays[0]);
}
echo array_intersect_multi([[1,2,3,4,5],[1,3,5],[1,3,4,5],[1,3,5,6,7,8,9]]);
// output: 1, 3, 5
```

This assumes you will package the individual arrays into an indexed array of arrays.

---

I also considered a recursive function, but recursion is slower and uses more memory.

```
function array_intersect_multi($arrays){ // recursive method
    if(sizeof($arrays)>1){
        $arrays[1]=array_intersect($arrays[0],$arrays[1]);  // find common values from first and second subarray, store as (overwrite) second subarray
        array_shift($arrays);  // discard first subarray (reindex $arrays)
        return array_intersect_multi($arrays);  // recurse
    }
    return implode(', ',$arrays[0]);
}
```

---

Furthermore, if you are happy to flatten your arrays into one with `array_merge()` and declare the number of individual arrays being processed, you can use this:

> (fastest method)

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/GOqVr/perf#output))

```
function flattened_array_intersect($array,$total_arrays){
    return implode(', ',array_keys(array_intersect(array_count_values($array),[$total_arrays])));
}
echo flattened_array_intersect(array_merge([1,2,3,4,5],[1,3,5],[1,3,4,5],[1,3,5,6,7,8,9]),4);
```

or replace `array_intersect()` with `array_filter()` (slightly slower and more verbose):

```
function flattened_array_intersect($array,$total_arrays){
    return implode(', ',array_keys(array_filter(array_count_values($array),function($v)use($total_arrays){return $v==$total_arrays;})));
}
echo flattened_array_intersect(array_merge([1,2,3,4,5],[1,3,5],[1,3,4,5],[1,3,5,6,7,8,9]),4);
```