# Object or Array for use case

Tags: php, arrays, object

I'm new to PHP and not sure, if I should use arrays or objects for my use case.

// Name
// Height
// Weight
// hair color

Possible array solution:

```
<?php
$Alex = array("Alex" "190","90","blond");
$Jim = array("Jim" "160","90","brown");
$Sarah = array("Sarah" "175","50","blond");
$Kevin = array("Kevin" "160","50","brown");
?>

$merged_arrays = array_merge( $Alex, $Jim, $Sarah, $Kevin);
```

Later the user should be able to select all 3 values (or just 1).

Example 1:
User selected:
Height "160" and hair color "brown" -> output should be "Jim" and "Kevin"

Example 2:
User selected: weight "50" -> output "Sarah" and " Kevin

I'm not sure IF it is smart to use arrays here, or maybe I should switch to objects, because all people will have the same values (names, height, weight and hair color).

IF arrays can solve that problem well, I'm not sure how to search and output the selected values like mentioned above.

I Found this, but it wasn't really helpful [Search Multiple Arrays for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13076747/search-multiple-arrays-for)

best regards

Comment: Use associative arrays. Use objects if you want to write object-oriented code.

Comment: `array("Alex" "190","90","blond");` is not a valid array. The same with your other arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will cover your example 1 with 2 possible solutions (foreach, array_filter) for both arrays and objects.

First arrays. For structured data you want to use associative arrays so your people have meaningful keys. Compare this:

```
$p = ["Alex", "190","90","blond"];
echo $p[2];
```

vs this:

```
$p = ['name' => "Alex", 'height' => "190", 'weight' => "90",'hair' => "blond";
echo $p['weight'];
```

Which one is easier to understand?

Also use correct types for your data. Height and weight can be int (or float) - not everything has to be string.

Associative arrays solution.

Create your data ($people) and your filter criteria ($criteria). $criteria can be dynamic, you can add or remove keys there

```
<?php

$alex = ['name' => 'Alex', 'height' => 190, 'weight' => 90, 'hair' => 'blond'];
$jim = ['name' => 'Jim', 'height' => 160, 'weight' => 90, 'hair' => 'brown'];
$sarah = ['name' => 'Sarah', 'height' => 175, 'weight' => 50, 'hair' => 'blond'];
$kevin = ['name' => 'Kevin', 'height' => 160, 'weight' => 50, 'hair' => 'brown'];

$people = [$alex, $jim, $sarah, $kevin];

var_dump($people);

$criteria = [ 
  'height' => 160,
  'hair' => 'brown',
];

// 1. search with foreach
$filteredPeople = [];
foreach ($people as $person) {
  $match = true;
  foreach ($criteria as $key => $value) {
    if ($person[$key] !== $value) {
      $match = false;
    }
  }

  if ($match) {
    $filteredPeople[] = $person;
  }
}

var_dump($filteredPeople);

// 2. use array_filter
$filteredPeople = array_filter($people, function (array $person) use ($criteria) {
  $match = true;
  foreach ($criteria as $key => $value) {
    if ($person[$key] !== $value) {
      $match = false;
    }
  }

  return $match;
});

var_dump($filteredPeople);
```

Output:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "Alex"
    ["height"]=>
    int(190)
    ["weight"]=>
    int(90)
    ["hair"]=>
    string(5) "blond"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "Jim"
    ["height"]=>
    int(160)
    ["weight"]=>
    int(90)
    ["hair"]=>
    string(5) "brown"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "Sarah"
    ["height"]=>
    int(175)
    ["weight"]=>
    int(50)
    ["hair"]=>
    string(5) "blond"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(4) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "Kevin"
    ["height"]=>
    int(160)
    ["weight"]=>
    int(50)
    ["hair"]=>
    string(5) "brown"
  }
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "Jim"
    ["height"]=>
    int(160)
    ["weight"]=>
    int(90)
    ["hair"]=>
    string(5) "brown"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "Kevin"
    ["height"]=>
    int(160)
    ["weight"]=>
    int(50)
    ["hair"]=>
    string(5) "brown"
  }
}
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "Jim"
    ["height"]=>
    int(160)
    ["weight"]=>
    int(90)
    ["hair"]=>
    string(5) "brown"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(4) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "Kevin"
    ["height"]=>
    int(160)
    ["weight"]=>
    int(50)
    ["hair"]=>
    string(5) "brown"
  }
}
```

This works, filters the data, you can specify criteria dynamically (0,1,2,3,4 criteria).

Object solution.

Now objects. My opinion is - if you have a structure for your data go with objects. They define structure, give you typehints, methods. You have place to add logic, validation. Want to add person with naame key (typo)? Not possible. Modify/overwrite some data by accident? Not possible. Want to validate that height cant be above 300? Add it to the constructor - in one place, etc. Also your IDE can help you much more because it also understands the data you work with.

Code is a little bit more complex (mapping criteria to getter methods for example):

```
<?php

class Person {
  private $name;
  private $height;
  private $weight;
  private $hair;

  public function __construct(string $name, int $height, int $weight, string $hair) {
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->height = $height;
    $this->weight = $weight;
    $this->hair = $hair;
  }

  public function getName(): string {
    return $this->name;
  }

  public function getHeight(): int {
    return $this->height;
  }

  public function getWeight(): int {
    return $this->weight;
  }

  public function getHair(): string {
    return $this->hair;
  }
}

$alex = new Person('Alex', 190, 90, 'blond');
$jim = new Person('Jim', 160, 90, 'brown');
$sarah = new Person('Sarah', 175, 50, 'blond');
$kevin = new Person('Kevin', 160, 50, 'brown');

$people = [$alex, $jim, $sarah, $kevin];

var_dump($people);

$criteria = [ 
  'height' => 160,
  'hair' => 'brown',
];

// 1. search with foreach
$filteredPeople = [];
foreach ($people as $person) {
  $match = true;
  foreach ($criteria as $key => $value) {
    switch ($key) {
      case 'name':
        $data = $person->getName();
        break;
      case 'height':
        $data = $person->getHeight();
        break;
      case 'weight':
        $data = $person->getWeight();
        break;
      case 'hair':
        $data = $person->getHair();
        break;
      default:
        throw new Exception('Unknown criteria: '.$key);
    }

    if ($data !== $value) {
      $match = false;
    }
  }

  if ($match) {
    $filteredPeople[] = $person;
  }
}

var_dump($filteredPeople);

// 2. use array_filter
$filteredPeople = array_filter($people, function (Person $person) use ($criteria) {
  $match = true;
  foreach ($criteria as $key => $value) {
    switch ($key) {
      case 'name':
        $data = $person->getName();
        break;
      case 'height':
        $data = $person->getHeight();
        break;
      case 'weight':
        $data = $person->getWeight();
        break;
      case 'hair':
        $data = $person->getHair();
        break;
      default:
        throw new Exception('Unknown criteria: '.$key);
    }

    if ($data !== $value) {
      $match = false;
    }
  }

  return $match;
});

var_dump($filteredPeople);
```

Output:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  object(Person)#1 (4) {
    ["name":"Person":private]=>
    string(4) "Alex"
    ["height":"Person":private]=>
    int(190)
    ["weight":"Person":private]=>
    int(90)
    ["hair":"Person":private]=>
    string(5) "blond"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(Person)#2 (4) {
    ["name":"Person":private]=>
    string(3) "Jim"
    ["height":"Person":private]=>
    int(160)
    ["weight":"Person":private]=>
    int(90)
    ["hair":"Person":private]=>
    string(5) "brown"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(Person)#3 (4) {
    ["name":"Person":private]=>
    string(5) "Sarah"
    ["height":"Person":private]=>
    int(175)
    ["weight":"Person":private]=>
    int(50)
    ["hair":"Person":private]=>
    string(5) "blond"
  }
  [3]=>
  object(Person)#4 (4) {
    ["name":"Person":private]=>
    string(5) "Kevin"
    ["height":"Person":private]=>
    int(160)
    ["weight":"Person":private]=>
    int(50)
    ["hair":"Person":private]=>
    string(5) "brown"
  }
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(Person)#2 (4) {
    ["name":"Person":private]=>
    string(3) "Jim"
    ["height":"Person":private]=>
    int(160)
    ["weight":"Person":private]=>
    int(90)
    ["hair":"Person":private]=>
    string(5) "brown"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(Person)#4 (4) {
    ["name":"Person":private]=>
    string(5) "Kevin"
    ["height":"Person":private]=>
    int(160)
    ["weight":"Person":private]=>
    int(50)
    ["hair":"Person":private]=>
    string(5) "brown"
  }
}
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  object(Person)#2 (4) {
    ["name":"Person":private]=>
    string(3) "Jim"
    ["height":"Person":private]=>
    int(160)
    ["weight":"Person":private]=>
    int(90)
    ["hair":"Person":private]=>
    string(5) "brown"
  }
  [3]=>
  object(Person)#4 (4) {
    ["name":"Person":private]=>
    string(5) "Kevin"
    ["height":"Person":private]=>
    int(160)
    ["weight":"Person":private]=>
    int(50)
    ["hair":"Person":private]=>
    string(5) "brown"
  }
}
```

People array, criteria array and filter code could also be objects in this solution, but I feel its out of the scope of this question.

Comment: Thanks for your awesome answer!

This is the explanation I was searching for.
I think that I will go for objects, because I have a structure for my data (in my example a database for fishes).
They all have the same structure / needs.

Within the object solution, i feel comfotable with the array_filter.
Using correct data types is a very good hint too!

You are running a foreach loop with switch cases.
So every case (criteria) will call the related function and save the value into data and break the loop?

But why is there so much output?
Shouldn't be the Jim the only output?

Comment: Take a look at switch documentation https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php . break is strictly connected with switch-case so it wont execute next case, not with breaking the loop. You could replace switch with ifelse chain.

Comment: There are 3 dumps in this code. 1st is the whole people array (so 4 elements). Then there is output for foreach solution and for array_filter solution. Both return 2 elements (Jim and Kevin) as you specified for your Example 1: 'height' => 160 and
'hair' => 'brown'.

Comment: Ah okay, now I understand everything! One var_dump($filteredPeople); after the array filter will only return Jim and Kevin. Thank you for helping me with your excellent answer including a good tutorial for understanding the problem and how to solve it. The next step I have to take is formatting the output, but that should be possible:) Have a great evening!

Comment: Is it possible that $filteredPeople contains 1 longs string: "Array ( [0] => Person Object ( [name:Person:private] => Alex [height:Person:private] => 190 [weight:Person:private] => 90 [hair:Person:private] => blond ) )" (even with print_r ($filteredPeople);). Is it possible to bind every value from the object to a single variable (to output them later)?. I changed the criteria a bit: https://codeshare.io/5OyrX7

Comment: @Aeris No, $filteredPeople is an array with People Objects. var_dump or print_r are functions that output information about expression you pass to them for debugging purposes (so they present string represenation of whatever you pass). You should not use them to present info for end user. You also rarely want to have all data from an object in a single string, because often you want to display it in a table or similar, where attibutes are in separate columns. Do this for example echo $filteredPeople[0]->getName(); etc, or foreach for all of them. It depends on how you want to present your data